# how to properly use checkboxInput on Shiny - R code

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a working app that I would like to enhance with a checkboxInput.

1> Here is a sample of the data:

```
     StudentID StudentGender GradeName    TermName MeasurementScaleName TestPercentile GoalRITScore1 GoalRITScore2 GoalRITScore3 GoalRITScore4
1         1374             M         3   Fall 2009              Reading             32           188           181           179            NA
50        1297             F         8   Fall 2009       Language Usage             48           224           214           209           228
101       1608             F         8   Fall 2009          Mathematics             40           225           210           211           244
1500      1286             M         1   Fall 2011       Language Usage             NA           218           225           238           221
2345      1196             F         8   Fall 2012       Language Usage             78           230           227           239           223
5498      1376             F         3 Spring 2010              Reading             24           188           194           185            NA
8954       486             M         2 Spring 2014              Reading              2           146           152           174            NA
9000       577             F         2 Spring 2014              Reading             71           196           189           207            NA
     GoalRITScore5 GoalRITScore6
1               NA            NA
50              NA            NA
101            233           227
1500            NA            NA
2345            NA            NA
5498            NA            NA
8954            NA            NA
9000            NA            NA
```

2> Here is part of the working script.
Shiny UI

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(navbarPage("MAP results",

  tabPanel("Summaries",

          sidebarLayout(

            sidebarPanel(
              selectInput("testname",           
                          "Select the test to visualize",
                          levels(mapdata$MeasurementScaleName)),
              selectInput("termname",         
                           "Select the term the test was taken",
                           levels(mapdata$TermName)),
              selectInput("ritorpercent",
                          "Display RIT scores or percentiles",
                          choices = c("RIT Scores", "Percentiles")),
              checkboxInput("gender", "Display Gender differences"),
              ),

          mainPanel(
            plotOutput("mapgraph")
            )
          )
        ),

  tabPanel("Growth visualizations")
        )
)
```

And part of the Server.R script.

## Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

mapdata <- read.csv("MAP data raw.csv")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$mapgraph <- renderPlot({

    graph1RIT <- reactive (mapdata %>% 
                             filter(TermName == input$termname, MeasurementScaleName == input$testname) %>% 
                             group_by(GradeName) %>% 
                             summarise(meanPer = mean(TestPercentile)))
    ggplot(graph1RIT(), aes(as.factor(GradeName), meanPer, fill = as.factor(GradeName))) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
      #coord_cartesian(ylim = c(150, 250)) + 
      labs(x = "Grade Level", y = "Mean RIT Percentile") + 
      guides(fill = FALSE)

  })
})
```

Now I want to use my checkboxInput("gender"), to make the same bargraph but with gender segregation.  ... and I thought I could just add this into the server.r

```
if(input$gender) {
      graph3RIT <- reactive (mapdata %>% 
                               filter(TermName == input$termname, MeasurementScaleName == input$testname) %>% 
                               group_by(GradeName, StudentGender) %>% 
                               summarise(meanPer = mean(TestPercentile)))
      ggplot(graph3RIT(), aes(as.factor(GradeName), meanPer, fill = as.factor(StudentGender))) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
        labs(x = "Grade Level", y = "Mean RIT Percentile")
    }
```

But if I do that, then the first graph doesn't show up anymore.  I've tried to look on the showmeshiny website for similar situation, but all the ones I could find didn't have the code available.

Any guidance on how I could use that checkbox, to change the graph

Comment: can you `dput` your data sample so we can load it into R by copy/pasting?

Comment: @NicE, the dataset is over 9,000 rows with 34 variables.  I just put 8 random rows there with only the variables that are of interest.

Comment: OK ... thanks NicE.  I did figure it out in the meantime.  All I needed to do was to put my code in between else {}.  Then it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Franky found the answer on his own. He wrote in the comments

> OK ... thanks NicE. I did figure it out in the meantime. All I needed
>   to do was to put my code in between else {}. Then it worked nicely. –
>   Franky Feb 10 '15 at 9:43

Comment: this doesn't add any value, pls delete it

Comment: @Creos Actually... The proper way to close out a question is for an answer to be posted, and accepted. What Bendaua posted was the answer, originally buried in comments. I see this as a proper answer (even if the OP didn't post it themselves).

Comment: @DavidMakogon ah you are right, i misread response, thx for correcting me

Comment: if you edit the response i'll be able to undo the downvote... however frivolous edits are generally frowned upon unless it's done by the author i guess